# Is it possible to show child over parents overlay

Tags: html, css

please, is there any way, to show child over parents overlay? 
What I want to achieve - I have div #wrapper, which has overlay with some color but I want to show one of its childs elements over this overlay. It means -> over #wrapper, there will be white transparent overlay and over overlay there will be #wrappers childs.

I have this code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="overlay-visible"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper::before{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    display: block;
    content: "";
}
#wrapper .overlay-visible {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: "child over parents" this is how it should work by default, can you create a jsfiddle, using just what you've posted doesnt show enough about your implemention

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/94ay10xq/

Comment: Ditto http://jsfiddle.net/94ay10xq/1/ even without `z-index` on the child

Comment: Yeah, here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/L34Lc14d/ 
I find out, that here it works, but when I use this in my website, I cannot make it working :/ 
Probably its because of positions abslute and relatives... I will rewrite exactly the structure I have and post it

Comment: Interesting... I update jsfiddle and rewrite it into structure, I have, also with positions relative and absolute and it works, how it should. Do you have any idea, where might be complication?

Comment: Oh, I find it out... it was because of animation on the element... :D

Answer (score -1):

With the z-index property. The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp